# Content-Type is not supported in Camel DELETE method?

Tags: java, apache-camel

How do i send content-type in Camel DELETE method. I have added the following way but It was not working correctly.

```
from("direct:start")
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, simple("DELETE"))
.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, simple("application/xml")) 
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple("http://02.02.02.02:8080/rest/delete/student/688187"))
.to("http://emptyhost");
```

**Could you please help me to resolve this issue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in a delete operation, no content is sent, the `Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE` property should not be needed.

Please, try

```
from("direct:start")
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, simple("DELETE"))
    .to("http://02.02.02.02:8080/rest/delete/student/688187");
```

or

```
from("direct:start")
    .to("restlet:http://02.02.02.02:8080/rest/delete/student/688187?restletMethod=delete");
```

By the way, using `delete` in the URL is not the RESTful way and should be ommited.

**EDIT:**

Camel does not transfer the body to the request of a `DELETE` operation, as can be seen digging into the source code. Use a `PUT` operation instead. 
See my answer to your other [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876781/how-to-call-rest-api-delete-operation-with-body-content-from-apache-camel/22877338#22877338).

Comment: I can understand What you are trying to convey. But as per our requirement we are sending content type to delete particular record. Could you give me an IDEA?

Comment: @AzhaguvelA With `DELETE` the body content is not transferred. I added a link to your other SO in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876781/how-to-call-rest-api-delete-operation-with-body-content-from-apache-camel/22877338#22877338) mentions, camel can process body if request method is delete in HTTP method.

Camel version 2.19.0 in http4 component with deleteWithBody option. We could just add it to the URL and use the http method as DELETE

Answer (score 0):

Content-type/body content is supported in apache camel through producer template with query param "deleteWithBody" by default it will be false.

```
String endpoint = https://testuri.com/resource;
endpoint = https://testuri.com/resource?deleteWithBody=true;
Exchange exchange;
exchange.getIn.setBody("test");
exchange.getIn.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
ProducerTemplate template = exchange.set(endpoint, exchange);
```