# How to call Rest API DELETE operation with BODY content from Apache Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I need to call rest DELETE operation with body content. I have alternative way to do this but this is our requirement. I have tried the following way but unable to get an output. Can you give me an IDEA to achieve this?

**Here's my code :**

```
from("direct:start")
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, simple("DELETE"))
.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_LENGTH, simple("64"))
.setBody(simple("<stundent>...</student>")))
.to("http://10.1.1.1:8080/rest/student/delete/1029");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in your other [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715289/content-type-is-not-supported-in-camel-delete-method), do not use a `DELETE` but a `PUT` operation.

**EDIT:**

Digging into the source code of [`HttpProducer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.camel/camel-http/2.12.1/org/apache/camel/component/http/HttpProducer.java), you can see that the request is filled if `methodToUse.isEntityEnclosed()` is `true` (line 367). However, this is only the case for `PUT` and `POST` as only those method implementations extend the class [`EntityEnclosingMethod`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/EntityEnclosingMethod.html). Unfortunately for you, this is not the case for `DELETE`.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts Peter, Actually We don't have an option to modify the existing API which was developed by someone. We should use their API to do the DELETE operation. That's why I am going to this way... Can you give me an IDEA via DELETE operation?

Comment: @AzhaguvelA Using Camel, this is not possible via `DELETE` as can be seen looking at the source code. I added a link to `HttpProducer` to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, the feature is available from Camel version 2.19.0 in http4 component with deleteWithBody option. We could just add it to the URL like below.

`.to(http4://10.1.1.1:8080/rest/student/delete/1029?deletewithBody=true)`

For Reference

- Sample [Camel Test Case](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/7657d7718b328c1f676e2574f8678b8dd99379e0/components/camel-http4/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/http4/HttpMethodsTest.java#L211)
- Source Code [HttpProducer](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/781330f188193905330f449314019ea4bdb00730/components/camel-http4/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/http4/HttpProducer.java#L455)