# Camel Rest. Can receive body on DELETE, but can't send it

Tags: java, http, apache-camel

I have two apps. First of them executes some business logics and than calls other app with POST or DELETE

```
from("direct:firstapp").routeId("rst_firstapp").streamCaching()
    //data preparation was here
    .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, simple(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
    .convertBodyTo(MyRequest.class)
    .choice().id("rst_req_lockCardChoice")
        .when().simple("${mycondition} == '1'")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, simple("POST"))
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Call post")
        .when().simple("${mycondition} == '0'")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, simple("DELETE"))
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Call delete")
    .end()
    .marshal(new JsonDataFormat(JsonLibrary.Jackson))
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, " Call to service ${body}")
    .to('myadress/mypath').id("rt_call_service")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, " Response from service ${body}");
```

Logs for line: .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, " Call to service ${body}")
print that body exists in both cases.

The second app receives this requests and does some other business logics.

```
rest().post("/mypath")
        .consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .type(MyRequest.class)
        .responseMessage().code("200").message("Success").endResponseMessage()
        .route().routeId("rst_postrecieve")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Recieved request ${body}")
        .id("rst_rst_post_recieved")
        .to("direct:drt_rst_postbranch")
        .endRest();

rest().delete("/mypath")
        .consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .type(MyRequest.class)
        .responseMessage().code("200").message("Success").endResponseMessage()
        .route().routeId("rst_deleterecive")
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Received request ${body}")
        .id("rst_rst_delete_recieved")
        .to("direct:drt_rst_deletebrach")
        .endRest();
```

POST request works fine.
First app sends body. Second recieves it.

DELETE doesn't.
First app cuts the body out. Line .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, " Call to service ${body}") prints the body. But the reciever gets a DELETE request with empty body. I have sniffed the Http-request with Wireshark: the body is empty.

However, I'm perfectly able to send a DELETE request with body using any other tool like Swagger-ui, Postman, Soap-UI etc. The second app will recieve body and proccess it correctly.

Why does Camel forbid to send a DELETE body, while it allows to recieve it? I expected the behaviour to be the same.

What is the workaround? I can't change request type, it's a customer requirement.

Camel version: 2.21.0.000033-fuse-000001-redhat-1

P.S. I know that Http standards state that no body is expected for DELETE, however all the tools & frameworks I faced allowed to send and receive it. Including Spring, for example.

Comment: This is a known issue. Apache camel doesn't send body in case of DELETE operation. use PUT instead.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably Delete method will ignore body while processing. This is no problem with your code, it was because of HTTP implementation.

> If a DELETE request includes an entity body, the body is ignored [...]

If you still need to send some data from one app to another to Delete method. I suggest you can try with path param. So than you can get as parameter in second app and do you process.

Comment: Point is: body in delete request is processed while recieving, but ignored in the process of sending. And only in Camel.

Comment: I am not sure whether we can use Delete in camel or not, mostly PUT will do think so. Refer this for more [Stack Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715289/content-type-is-not-supported-in-camel-delete-method)